# Короткое тире в сложном промежутке

Tags: пунктуация, пробелы

Нужно ли отделять пробелами короткое тире, например, в таком случае:

август 2015 – март 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**В Вашем примере пробелы нужны.** А вот насчет собственно "короткого" тире и т.н. "отбивки" применительно к этому случаю - это отдельный разговор.

Это вопросы не совсем по русскому языку. В правилах русской орфографии (в широком смысле, т.е. собственно орфографии и пунктуации) есть знак *тире* (пунктуационный) и знак *дефис* (орфографический). Ни про размеры, ни про пробелы вокруг тире в случаях его нестандартного применения ничего  не говорится. Что говорят правила? Они говорят о том, что рядом с дефисом пробелы невозможны (кроме случая т.н. висячего дефиса в конструкциях типа "теле- и радиовещание" - хотя и по ним сейчас ведутся споры), а вот тире в большинстве случаев (об исключениях - ниже) отделяется от текста пробелами. Обратите внимание, [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire)(кликабельно!) нет ни одного упоминания о пробелах, как нет и ни одного примера использования тире без пробелов. Остальное уже не относится к правописанию.

Но есть сложившиеся типографские правила, обычно ими и оперируют, давая рекомендации по оформлению того или иного случая. Беда в том, что эти типографские правила никогда не были собраны в единый свод, безусловно авторитетный для всех. Есть Мильчин, конечно, но это тоже не Библия в последней редакции. Тем более нет единства понимания при использовании компьютерных систем верстки (а кто сейчас вручную набирает?), подвязанных на конкретные технические возможности программного обеспечения и устройств.

По сложившейся практике, если опустить некоторые совсем уж малоактуальные подробности, то большинство комментаторов типографских правил *длинным* называют тире, которое требует окружения пробелами, а *коротким* (или средним, если коротким считается знак минуса, графически отличный от дефиса) - то, которое пробелов вокруг себя не требует.

В каких же случаях ставится короткое тире (и соответственно - без пробелов)? Только когда это тире соединяет два объекта связанные в одно целое (диапазон, имена собственные в особо употреблении и т.д.), причем эти объекты сами по себе не содержат пробелов. Это случаи §§ 178-179 указанных правил. Вот в этих-то случаях (только в них!), в типографиях договорились использовать для зрительной наглядности особого начертания тире ("короткое") и не отделять его полноценными пробелами от соединяемых им объектов. При этом какие-то "полупробелы" или "четвертьпробелы" можно делать даже вокруг короткого тире, если это позволяет набор шрифтов и используемая издательская система.

Ваш пример не подпадает под разобранное уже потому, что соединяемые объекты (границы диапазона) не представляют собой однословные (написанные без пробелов) объекты. И значит, тире нужно длинное, т.е. с пробелами.

Обратите внимание, что написанное через дефис трактуется как в одно слово.

И о термине "отбивка". Это тоже из типографии, не из русского языка. Ничего бы страшного, но термин путаный. Обычно отбивками называют особый пробел, стоящий между частями целого (обычно он соответствует т.н. *неразрывным пробелам*, хотя это вещи разные), например, между значением (в цифрах) физической величины и её обозначением или числом знаком процента. Этот пробел как правило короче обычного. Очень сомнительно, что в рассматриваемом случае длинного тире правомерно называть пробелы вокруг него отбивками. Хотя это тоже вопрос терминологический, но за ним стоит типографская практика.

Итак. Если следовать наиболее общим рекомендациям. ***Короткое тире без пробелов. Длинное с пробелами. Собственно размер типографского знака при этом не регламентируется.***

Примеры:
капитан-лейтенант (короткое тире),
старший лейтенант - инженер (длинное тире),
рейс *Нью-Йорк--Сан-Франциско* (короткое тире, хотя графически надо делать длиннее для зрительного восприятия, о кавычках тут разговор особый),
**август 2015 – март 2016** (длинное тире, хотя графически может быть короче обычного).

*И ещё. Никогда не переносите на русскую типографику, тем более - пунктуацию, правила из других языков. И наоборот. (Это в огород Galina Avanesova).*

Comment: >> *есть знак тире (пунктуационный) и знак дефис - пунктуационный*.     Орфографический!

Comment: Да, конечно! Спасибо, именно это и хотел сказать.

Comment: @behemothus "старший лейтенант - инженер (длинное тире)" . Это ошибка, правописание подобных званий производится согласно Приказу Министра обороны 1971 года только через дефис. Впрочем и до 71 года было то же самое, только слова "инженер", "техник" писались(и произносились до звания, но также через дефис. Правильно следует писать "старший лейтенант-техник", "капитан II ранга-инженер", "генерал-лейтенант-инженер", "капитан-лейтенант-техник" и т.д.

Comment: Дорогой мой, никогда еще министерство обороны не отдавало приказы русскому языку. А тут "согласно приказу" получается глупость.

Answer (score 1):

Тире не отбивается только между цифрами/числами в значении «от — до» (например, 1634—1699). Между словами или если вмешались слова - всегда отбивка.

> Тире, обозначающее диапазон значений, границы которого заданы числами
> (1941—1945, XVI—XVII), пробелами не отбивают.

Есть понятие [среднего тире](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5) (en dash); короткое - это уже дефис.

**СРЕДНЕЕ ТИРЕ**

> используется для обозначения диапазонов и интервалов (June–July 1967,
> For ages 3–5, New York–London flight), соединения сложных слов,
> содержащих дефисы (high-priority–high-pressure tasks), и разделения
> заголовков в составных названиях (как правило, музыкальных релизов и
> компьютерных игр: Rockin’ Every Night – Live in Japan; Dragon Age:
> Origins – Awakening).

Вот, по-моему, с "New York–London flight" придумщики примера погорячились: нужны здесь отбивки. А то York–London какой-то.

Comment: Придумщики погорячились совсем в другом языке. По-русски пишут Нью-Йорк. И иные правила.